# Mail send html in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I have a problem
I want to send a html sting by c# in asp.net mvc
when i use readalltoend a html page by streamreader it works good
But !!!
I need to get a string like this :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
//some html code
</body>
</html>
```

I get this as a string an try to send it , when it sended it has no style and show like a string not html
I've tried with streamwriter to write it to a html file and read it again but it doesn't solve my problem
plz help me

Comment: Which library do you use to send mails and could you provide code snippet of mail sending method?

Comment: my mail isn't spam , and i've used isbodyhtml=true , but the problem is there , i copy my html code in a gmail->new mail and it doesn't show my style too

Comment: i use System.Net.Mail

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `System.Net.Mail` and you want to send html as the message, make sure your set :

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If possible I'd actually recommend using MIME rather than HTML. Many spam filters don't like emails which don't have a plaintext version included. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483799/how-to-send-multi-part-mime-messages-in-c

Comment: I never ran into this problem, maybe it's because i use a trusted mail server which helps with passing spamfilters. However this is a good suggestion, I will also have a look myself at this link

Comment: it's just one of many many factors I've found which may sometimes trip a spam filter. If you're not having trouble I suggest you don't mess with it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504911/sending-email-with-php-and-ensuring-it-doesnt-get-blocked/9505137#9505137

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
MvcMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
```