# How to add headers "To and Reply-To" to an already generated Draft with the GMAIL API

Tags: email, nuget, gmail, gmail-api, mimekit

I created a draft message and attached it correctly to a gmail thread with the Gmail Api.
But I have no clue how to add the "To, and Reply-To" to that draft. At this point, the draft appears without the "TO" value added to it in gmail.
I searched on Stackoverflow and found a solution using AE.NET.MAIL . See : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787230/how-to-create-a-gmail-api-message#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787230/how-to-create-a-gmail-api-message#_=_)

However that nuget seems not to allow adding it to a thread.

So basically I am needing to :
1) Have a solution for adding the TO to my current Gmail created draft solution.
2) Or to have a solution for adding the generated draft to the thread, if it's possible at all with AE.NET.MAIL or MIMEKIT nuget.

Which way should I go?
thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you already created a mail draft with Gmail API, and you now want to specify a *to* address. If that is the case, you can add them as payload headers of the message as described [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource). Those headers must comply with the standard [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) (*Internet Message Format*). You can see a detailed example [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending). Please, don't hesitate to ask further doubts.