# Use Google Drive-api to attach files from Drive to a specific Gmail address

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I use the code below to receive all the files from my drive account:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }
        Console.Read();

    }


}
```

after running this, I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3tUC.png)

which is great, i get all my files i got in my drive account.

now, I want to take each file and attach and send it to a particular Gmail address.

any ideas what I should do now?

Answer (score 0):

This may still depend on your implementation but you can use the Gmail API to attach the drive files and send it to a specific users.

Here is a code snippet for sending mail:

```
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /// <summary>
  /// Send an email from the user's mailbox to its recipient.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="service">Gmail API service instance.</param>
  /// <param name="userId">User's email address. The special value "me"
  /// can be used to indicate the authenticated user.</param>
  /// <param name="email">Email to be sent.</param>
  public static Message SendMessage(GmailService service, String userId, Message email)
  {
      try
      {
          return service.Users.Messages.Send(email, userId).Execute();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      }

      return null;
  }

  // ...

}
```

Here's some related references that can help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26661866/5995040
- https://ctrlq.org/code/20132-gmail-api-send-mail-attachments (This is web sample but process and implementation would be the same)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26408840/5995040

Hope this helps.

Comment: but for that, i have to download each file from my Google Drive account to my Computer using google-drive-api and than for attach each file i have to use gmail-api.
am i right?